# Issue with plotting in a for loop on matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, plot, matlab-figure

This is my `for` loop, which is not plotting correctly:

```
for w=1:1:1000
    s(w)=w*1j;
    hX(w)=(alphaX22_1+betaX22_1*s(w))/(s(w)^2+2*d_X1*wn_X1*s(w)+wn_X1^2)+...
    (alphaX22_2+betaX22_2*s(w))/(s(w)^2+2*d_X2*wn_X2*s(w)+wn_X2^2);

    mag_hX(w)=sqrt(real(hX(w))^2+imag(hX(w))^2);
    %arg_hX(w)=atan(imag(hX(w))/real(hX(w)));    
end

figure(2)
plot(w,mag_hX(w),'+')
```

But I only get the last value on the plot. Also when I do 'size s' or 'size hX' I get 1 1, but I can access s(350) and hX(350).

Just so you can run the code, I am adding the numerical values of my variables.

```
% Natural Frequencies and Damping Ratios
wn_X1=354.3; d_X1=0.038;
wn_X2=467.6; d_X2=0.049;

alphaX22_1 = 0.0043
betaX22_1 = -1.2528e-05
alphaX22_2 = 0.0235
betaX22_2 = 4.4012e-06
```

Comment: Better to use `plot(mag_hX, '+')` as `w` is a single value.

Comment: Mikkola: Just did that, all my data points are on w=1000 (vertical line) instead of being over the w=1:1000 interval if that makes sense

Comment: `plot(1:1000,mag_hX, '+')` !!?? ;)

Comment: Madcuf: Thanks that does work :)

Comment: @macduf Oops. Thanks for the correction! :) Removing my original comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a closer look at [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html?refresh=true) or [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/90680-plotting-in-a-for-loop). I believe you need to put your plotting statement in the for loop. Right now you're only plotting the last value. You should open the figure before your loop.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: lol sorry, new here, which is why I couldn't comment, but thanks for the kind advise.

Comment: @M.Smith not being able to comment does not mean to post your comment as an answer

Comment: new here, also meaning, I didn't know, so once again thanks!

Comment: How is this not an answer? The problem was "I only get the last value on the plot", and @M.Smith provided the solution "Open the figure before your loop."